# Tiled Galleries Link Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, hyperlink, gallery

I'm using Jetpack's "Tiled Galleries", and I would like for each picture in the gallery, to redirect me to the the post where the image is used. When "Link to:" is set to "Attachment URL" i get redirected to the page:

Example:

```
http://www.regnfang.com/journalism/post2/img_0755/
```

But instead i would like to be redirected to:

```
 http://www.regnfang.com/journalism/post2/
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

[A reply on the WP.org forums](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/can-tiled-gallery-images-not-link-to-anything#post-5253382) seems to indicate that you might be able to use the [WP Gallery Custom Links](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-gallery-custom-links/) plugin. Not tested this though.

Comment: Thanks! This plugin helped!

Comment: Great :) Glad to be of help.